How to set up apache2 in webserver
I have set up how to video show in youtube. I have order in real web server. The provider give me IP. I have the registration in my domain name. Default page in apache2 is worked. But through be domain name don't worked. How to fix my problem?
MY ROOTDOCUMENT FOLDER IS
/var/armyt.com.tm/index.html
/etc/apache2/sites-available/armyt.com.tm.conf

/etc/hostname
armyt.com.tm
/etc/hosts

Ufw

I have more again.
In sudo a2dissite armyt.com.tm and reload apache2 and again sudo a2ensite armyt.com.tm and reload apache2, but it doesn't work in my domain name through the web browser.

There is the default apache web page at 216.250.13.42. The DNS records for armyt.com.tm and www.armyt.com.tm point to 216.250.13.0 and there is no response on port 80 from that IP address.

How to write correctly

What IP address did your provider give you? Was it 216.250.13.42 or 216.250.13.0 or something else? You need to have your DNS records reflect your actual IP address. You can help us to help you by not posting pictures, but rather post the actual text.

216.250.13.42 this Ip

Then you need to get your DNS records to resolve to that IP address. Currently they do not.

I try, but don't helping

The master DNS records are fixed, and have propagated to other DNSs. The default apache web page now displays via URL.

Yes, is worked, you are right,  thank you!!!
